# Do Content Security Policies support a wildcard suffix for the top-level domain?

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I have a Content Security Policy img-src I am unable to configure. The URL being requested has a dot country code suffix.

Example:

In Hong Kong = [www.example.com.hk](http://www.example.com.hk)

In Thailand = [www.example.com.th](http://www.example.com.th)

Is there a way to add a wildcard to the end of a path? all the documentation I can find uses wildcards as a prefix.

I have tried www.example.com.* but it's an invalid source.

Comment: the left-most part of a domain is the top-most level. and I don't think you mean "path". what you're showing is the top-level domain.

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources#sources):

> Internet hosts by name or IP address, as well as an optional URL scheme and/or port number. The site's address may include an optional ***leading wildcard*** (the asterisk character, '*'), and you may use a wildcard (again, '*') as the port number, indicating that all legal ports are valid for the source.

Nowhere does it say a wildcard can be used anywhere else.

While for you it may seem convenient in this specific context, in the bigger picture it would be a strange and probably dangerous thing to allow wildcarding the toplevel domain. Each toplevel domain is *separately* authoritative for the domains below it. There is no rule that says that `www.example.com.hk` and `www.example.com.th` must be owned by the same entity, and the same goes for the same-origin-policy. If that happens to be the case, it should be seen as coincidental.

You can use [csp-evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) to try out CSP values and see what they mean.